# Prevent Mysterious String-to-Number Conversion of Color Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="">
        <select name="fancySelect" class="makeMeFancy">
            <option value="0" selected="selected" data-skip="1">Email Color Scheme</option>
            <option value="81" data-color1="993300" data-color2="000000" data-html-text="Brown on Black">Brown on Black</option>
            <option value="77" data-color1="663366" data-color2="000000" data-html-text="Purple on Black">Purple on Black</option>
            <option value="129" data-color1="00ccff" data-color2="000000" data-html-text="Teal on Black">Teal on Black</option>
            <option value="75" data-color1="666666" data-color2="000000" data-html-text="Dark Gray on Black">Dark Gray on Black</option>
            <option value="85" data-color1="999999" data-color2="000000" data-html-text="Gray on Black">Gray on Black</option>
            <option value="81" data-color1="993300" data-color2="000000" data-html-text="Brown on Black">Brown on Black</option>
            <option value="77" data-color1="663366" data-color2="000000" data-html-text="Purple on Black">Purple on Black</option>
            <option value="129" data-color1="00ccff" data-color2="000000" data-html-text="Teal on Black">Teal on Black</option>
            <option value="75" data-color1="666666" data-color2="000000" data-html-text="Dark Gray on Black">Dark Gray on Black</option>
            <option value="85" data-color1="999999" data-color2="000000" data-html-text="Gray on Black">Gray on Black</option>
            <option value="81" data-color1="993300" data-color2="000000" data-html-text="Brown on Black">Brown on Black</option>
            <option value="77" data-color1="663366" data-color2="000000" data-html-text="Purple on Black">Purple on Black</option>
            <option value="129" data-color1="00ccff" data-color2="000000" data-html-text="Teal on Black">Teal on Black</option>
            <option value="75" data-color1="666666" data-color2="000000" data-html-text="Dark Gray on Black">Dark Gray on Black</option>
            <option value="85" data-color1="999999" data-color2="000000" data-html-text="Gray on Black">Gray on Black</option>
        </select>
    </form>
```

jQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // The select element to be replaced:
    var select = $('select.makeMeFancy');

    var selectBoxContainer = $('<div>',{
        width       : select.outerWidth(),
        className   : 'tzSelect',
        html        : '<div class="selectBox"></div>'
    });

    var dropDown = $('<ul>',{className:'dropDown'});
    var selectBox = selectBoxContainer.find('.selectBox');

    // Looping though the options of the original select element

    select.find('option').each(function(i){
        var option = $(this);

        if(i==select.attr('selectedIndex')){
            selectBox.html(option.text());
        }

        // As of jQuery 1.4.3 we can access HTML5 
        // data attributes with the data() method.

        if(option.data('skip')){
            return true;
        }


        // Creating a dropdown item according to the
        // data-icon and data-html-text HTML5 attributes:

        var li = $('<li>',{
            html:   '<table border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3"><tr valign="middle"><td bgcolor="#'+option.data(String('color1'))+'" class="color">&nbsp;</td><td bgcolor="#'+option.data(String('color2'))+'" class="color">&nbsp;</td><td class="text"><span>'+option.data('html-text')+'</span></td></tr></table>'
        });

        li.click(function(){
            selectBox.html("<div id='selected-colors'><div id='color-selection1' style='background:#"+ option.data(String('color1')) +";'></div><div id='color-selection2' style='background:#"+ option.data(String('color2')) +";'></div><span>"+option.data('html-text')+"</span>");
            dropDown.trigger('hide');

            // When a click occurs, we are also reflecting
            // the change on the original select element:
            select.val(option.val());

            return false;
        });

        dropDown.append(li);
    });

    selectBoxContainer.append(dropDown.hide());
    select.hide().after(selectBoxContainer);

    // Binding custom show and hide events on the dropDown:

    dropDown.bind('show',function(){

        if(dropDown.is(':animated')){
            return false;
        }

        selectBox.addClass('expanded');
        dropDown.slideDown();

    }).bind('hide',function(){

        if(dropDown.is(':animated')){
            return false;
        }

        selectBox.removeClass('expanded');
        dropDown.slideUp();

    }).bind('toggle',function(){
        if(selectBox.hasClass('expanded')){
            dropDown.trigger('hide');
        }
        else dropDown.trigger('show');
    });

    selectBox.click(function(){
        dropDown.trigger('toggle');
        return false;
    });

    // If we click anywhere on the page, while the
    // dropdown is shown, it is going to be hidden:

    $(document).click(function(){
        dropDown.trigger('hide');
    });
});
```

In the drop down of the option list, the BLACK in data-color-2 shows up fine, but is populated with a bgcolor of '0' instead of the 000000 that I have in the option data-color2.  What do I need to add to the code to force that BOTH data-color1 and data-color2 are both STRINGS and not INTEGERS?

Comment: You should post the actual code involved.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code as to how your setting those data attributes?

Comment: modified question to include actual code

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jQuery `.data()` method intentionally transforms the attribute contents. It thinks it's doing you a favor, but often (as in your case) it's not.

You could add "#" to your color attributes. That'd cause the attempt to convert to a number to fail, and you'd end up with a string.

Alternatively, you could use a single attribute for both colors, in the form of a JSON literal:

```
 <option value="81" data-colors='{ "color1": "993300", "color2": "000000" }' data-html-text="Brown on Black">Brown on Black</option>
```

In the JavaScript code, you'd get an object and refer to the colors:

```
    var colors = option.data("colors");
```

Then `colors.color1` and `colors.color2` will be proper strings, because your JSON notation explicitly describes them as such.

*edit* — an insightful comment points out that the numeric conversion is only done when the result of the conversion is a number that, when stringified again, is the same as the original string.

*edit again* — The JSON needs to be valid, so the property names need to be in double quotes. My apologies.

[Here is a working jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/khmy378u/)

Comment: `data()` won't change `"000000"` to `0`. From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/): _"[...] "1E02" and "100.000" are equivalent as numbers (numeric value 100) but converting them would alter their representation so they are left as strings._"  It _will_ parse `"993300"` as an int... but that shouldn't affect string concatenation. http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/r180cvhr/

Comment: @canon ah yes, it looks like it only does the numeric conversion if the result re-stringifies as the same string. In this particular situation I think I'd still use some more explicit and predictable way of avoiding that nicety, but I'm kind-of risk-averse.

Comment: I certainly agree with your use of JSON. I was merely pointing out that bit about conversion. I dislike the `data()` method entirely. :/

Comment: @Pointy I have implemented the example above, as but I could, but when I put colors.color1 in where option.data(String('color1')) all I get is undefined.  should I be wrapping the colors.color1 or colors.color2 in anything?

Comment: @Murphy1976 well you have to make sure you fetch the object, `var colors = option.data("colors");` - I'll workj on a jsfiddle implementation.

Comment: @Murphy1976 apologies, my friend, my example was incorrect. I am going to fix it now.

Comment: I actually found out me REAL issue here. After looking at your jFiddle, and then incorporating mine into a different fiddle, I quickly realized that the major difference was that I am referencing jQuery 1.4.3 in my HTML, and once I referenced the latest version of jQuery... all hell broke loose.  Nothing showed up at all.  I still believe your answer to be the correct one, even though I am forced to take a different path on this project. Thank you for your help, I did learn a lot from this.

Comment: @Murphy1976 wow!  OK, well a good lesson you've stumbled across is that web technologies change very quickly - an article from 2010 is, in some ways, inherently suspicious because so many things may have changed since then. Good luck!!